# Выборка из 2х таблиц

Tags: c#

Есть 2 таблички, у которых общее значение Name с ключом. Таблицы Char и GMember. С таблицы Char мы достали нужные данные к каждому Name и получили список по убыванию, а вот к сожалению достать значение G_Name из таблички GMember и прикрутить его к текущему списку не получается. Прошу не бить палками, новички.

Запросили мы некий список из таблички Char

```
using (DataBase entity = new DataBase())
{
    repeater.DataSource = entity.Char
                    .OrderByDescending(ob => ob.RCount)
                    .ThenByDescending(ob => ob.Level)
                    .Take(50).ToList();

    repeater.DataBind();
}
```

.ascx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>                
            <td><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Level") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("RCount") %></td>
            <td><%=Functions.GCount %></td>    
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

В итоге был получен нужный нам список, кроме значения GCount. Потому как для каждого значения Name в Char - своё значение GCount. В Functions он выглядит следующим образом:

```
public static string GCount
{
    get
    {
        using (DataBase entity = new DataBase())
        {
            var Count = entity.GMember
                          .Select(c => c.G_Name)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
            return Count.ToString();
        }
   }
}
```

Вообщем получили одно и то же значение GCount для всего списка. В базе данных кстати у таблицы Char и GMember одна и та же запись Name.

GMember

```
namespace Data.MsSql.DataBase
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("GMember")]
    public partial class GMember
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string G_Name { get; set; }

        public byte? G_Level { get; set; }

        public byte G_Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Char

```
namespace Data.MsSql.DataBase
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("Character")]
    public partial class Char
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string AccountID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? Level { get; set; }

        public int RCount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Предлагаете квест для ЧГК, чтобы вывели самостоятельно что у вас за таблицы или впишете в вопрос, чтобы облегчить понимание?

Comment: Рекомендую начинать программировать не со старых ASP.NET Forms а на современный ASP.NET Core 2.0. Смысл разбираться с технологией которая уже лет 7 как устарела.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но нам возникла необходимость к уже существующему форуму добавить пару страниц и не более. Поэтому пытаемся разобраться с текущим кодом.

Comment: Это EntityFramework?

Comment: Алексей добрый вечер. Для работы мы добавили модель ADO.NET EDM с использованием Code First из базы. Формировали модель с помощью EF 6.

Comment: Код класса GMember нужен и GChar, из вопроса непонятна их связь, и роль.

Comment: @That в сообщение добавьте, оба класса.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Обновил сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всём вашем коде я не разобрался, но суть понятна. Вам просто нужно биндить не сразу объекты базы данных а сначала подготовить данные, и создать на основе данных из DB классы ViewModel уже такими какими что бы им можно было отображать в ваших контролах.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! У нас есть таблица Char, из которой в порядке убывания нужно отсортировать 50 имён (Name) по значению RCount а затем Level. В итоге должен получиться некий список вида: 
MyName 12 200
MyName2 11 400
MyName3 8 300
И так далее. Используя код выше - получили, но спустя время понадобилось ещё одно значение из таблички GMember. В ней есть это же имя (Name) и у него своё значение G_Name, которое и нужно получить к существующему списку. То есть список выше должен иметь вид

Comment: MyName 12 200 Value
MyName2 11 400 Value2
MyName3 8 300 Value3
Если вас не затруднит - разжуйте пожалуйста на примере какого - нибудь куска кода, или посоветуйте опытного человека (не бесплатно). Почта playmusu@mail.ru

Comment: @That написал вам